# passing json data from python (bottle.py) to leaflet's javascript library to display on a slippy map

Tags: jquery, python, json, bottle, leaflet

I'm working on what I thought would be a simple side project.  It turns out that I am a bit out of my comfort zone since I know nothing about python (PHP is what I work with).  I am trying to create a slippy map (using cloudemade's leaflet) that displays a set of points of interests.  I have a CSV file containing name, latitude and longitude of the POIs.

So far I am able to read the CSV data and convert it to JSON data and display a dump of the JSON data in a web page using bottle.py.

My question is how do I pass bottle.py's JSON data to leaflet's javascript library via jquery??

Chris

Comment: I'm struggling with a similar problem, I might start a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

leaflet supports GEOJSON, which makes it easy to display vector data with leaflet.

See:

http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/examples/geojson.html

The python [geojson](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/geojson/) library supports geojson as well, so there's not a lot you need to do on the python side other than get it into the appropriate object and add any additional properties you want before serving the resulting JSON to leaflet.

Just use a standard XMLHttpRequest() to get the JSON objects from whereever you're serving it.

```
function loadData(){

    // retrieve and load features to a layer
    var xhrequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhrequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xhrequest.readyState == 4){
            if (xhrequest.status == 200){
                var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON();
                geojsonLayer.on("featureparse", function(e){
                    if (e.properties && e.properties.name && e.properties.value){
                        var popupContent = "Whatever added properties you want to display";
                        e.layer.bindPopup(popupContent);                     
                    }; 
                    // any styles you've added
                    if (e.properties && e.properties.style && e.layer.setStyle){
                        e.layer.setStyle(e.properties.style);                      
                    };                      
                });    
                var layerItems =  JSON.parse(xhrequest.responseText);
                // add features to layer
                for (i=0; i<layerItems.length;i++){
                    var geojsonFeature = layerItems[i];
                    geojsonLayer.addGeoJSON(geojsonFeature);                       
                };
                map.addLayer(geojsonLayer); 
            };                
        };            
    };
    var url= "<url of where you are serving the GEOJSON data>"; 
    xhrequest.open('GET', url, true);
    xhrequest.send(null);            
}
```